# mocking set_contents_from_filename of boto in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to write a unit test for `save_file_to_s3` method:

```
class S3Wrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, aws_key, aws_secret):
    self._s3_handle = S3Connection(aws_key, aws_secret)


  def save_file_to_s3(self, filename, bucket_name, key):

    bucket = self._s3_handle.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = key 
    k.set_contents_from_filename(filename)
```

How do i do this using mocktests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By patching the method directly on the class itself. For convenience, I usually turn these common mockings into decorators, like:

```
import mock
from boto.s3.key import Key

def mock_s3_key(func):
    def _mock_s3_key(*args, **kwargs):
        with mock.patch.object(Key, 'set_contents_from_filename', return_value=None):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _mock_s3_key


class YourTest(TestCase):

    @mock_s3_key
    def test_save_file_to_s3(self):
        # test code here
        pass
```